# Summing a list with lists inside

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sum, python-2.x

I am trying to sum the numbers in a list that contains lists itself:

ex: `list=['apple', [1], 'pineapple', [3]]`

could someone explain to me how I could do this?

Comment: So is your list always this format? `name`s alternated by a list of integers? Can there be multiple numbers per name? And what have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: please provide the desired output and your effort/attempt at it

Comment: `sum = list[1][0] + list[3][0]`

Comment: Why do your lists in lists contain only 1 number? Wouldn't `list = ['apple', 1, 'pineapple', 3]` be easier?

Answer (score 2):

You could recurse and sum anything that acts like a number

```
def sum_deep(lst):
    sum = 0
    for el in lst:
        if isinstance(el, list):
            sum += sum_deep(el)
        try:
            sum += el
        except TypeError:  # this isn't addable
            pass  # but that's okay
    return sum

lst = ['apple', [1], 'pineapple', [3]]
sum_deep(lst)  # 4
```

But ultimately you have a cooky data structure. Fix that instead.

Answer (score 2):

if all your numbers are lists inside your list you can do it like this:

```
l = ['apple', [1], 'pineapple', [3]]
print sum([sum(i) for i in l if isinstance(i, list)])
```

Output:

```
4
```